# Google Script Editor: copy and paste specific data range by dynamic "X"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working with a user group that does not feel comfortable with "select the bottom right corner and drag by whatever amount of cells you need" feature within sheets, so we're trying to come up with a solution where they can type in how many times they want to copy and paste a range and then have that happen in the next empty row(s) of the same table.

My initial instinct is to have an "entry" range in the first (non-header) row of my Sheets table, and an outside cell whose value determines how many times this range is copied and pasted in the next available row of the table below it. To clarify, the solution would look something like this:

1. You enter data into a single entry range, seen as B3:J3 below, where cell L3 would function as the "key" whereby you could enter a value\ indicating the amount of times you wish to copy and paste range B3:J3 in the rows below:
   [image]
2. As seen above, the user has begun the process of logging their first Rec ID (101) into the "editable" range (B3:J3). The user wants 10 of these, so they would enter 10 into cell L3, as seen below, which would then paste 10 times in the next available rows of range B4:J (in this case, the top of the table)
   [image]

The goal would be that the user could then clear range B3:J3, log a new "Rec" entry, which maybe only needs to be multiplied by 5, and it would paste without overwriting any data captured by log 101 (so B3:J3 and cell L3 would be constantly changing as more logs were made):
[image]

In all honesty, I am at an utter loss for how to proceed. I cannot find any kind of similar use case and am not sure if I'm looking for a Google sheets function, something in Script Editor, a macro, or even a specialty paste I'm not aware of. Any and all guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to achieve this using Google Apps Script? If it's so, how do you want to run the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting Copied Rows

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const entryRow = 3;
  const startCol = 2;
  const endCol = 11;
  const sheetname = 'Sheet1';
  if (sh.getName() == sheetname && e.range.columnStart == endCol + 1 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast('cond');
    let rg =  sh.getRange(entryRow, startCol, 1, endCol - startCol + 1);//entry data range
    let row = rg.getValues()[0];//entry row data
    let n = sh.getRange(entryRow, endCol + 1).getValue();//number of rows to insert
    sh.insertRows(entryRow + 1, n);//insert rows
    let arr = new Array(n);//create array
    let oA = Array.from(arr, r => row);//load rows into array
    sh.getRange(entryRow + 1, startCol, n, endCol - startCol + 1).setValues(oA);//load array into created rows
    rg.clearContent();//clears entry line
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

For Loading at the bottom try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const entryRow = 3;
  const startCol = 2;
  const endCol = 11;
  const sheetname = 'Sheet1';
  if (sh.getName() == sheetname && e.range.columnStart == endCol + 1 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast('cond');
    let lr=sh.getLastRow();
    let rg =  sh.getRange(entryRow, startCol, 1, endCol - startCol + 1);//entry data range
    let row = rg.getValues()[0];//entry row data
    let n = sh.getRange(entryRow, endCol + 1).getValue();//number of rows to insert
    sh.insertRows(lr + 1, n);//insert rows
    let arr = new Array(n);//create array
    let oA = Array.from(arr, r => row);//load rows into array
    sh.getRange(lr + 1, startCol, n, endCol - startCol + 1).setValues(oA);//load array into created rows
    rg.clearContent();//clears entry line
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this so I may need some mofication

Comment: oh this is awesome! is there a way to make it load down instead of up (so that the newest data appears below the older data)?

Comment: Hi Cooper - that worked so now the rows are inserting at the bottom (and thank you so very much) but we ran into another problem. We need the rows to just paste at the bottom so formulas in an adjacent table do not move around due to insertion -- any tips on how to edit the script to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have much experience in working with formulas because I never use them.  And I mean never.  So I believe that is something you're going to have to figure out yourself.